# Output some newlines through Makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile

Below is my makefile:

```
TARGET = prog
LIBS = -lm
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -pthread -Wextra -Wall -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wcast-qual -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum -Wconversion -Wunreachable-code

.PHONY: clean all default 

default: $(TARGET) clean 
all: default

OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard *.c))
HEADERS = $(wildcard *.h)

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PRECIOUS: $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -Wall $(LIBS) -o $@

clean:
    -rm -f *.o
```

With the flags above and a few files in the directory, the output makes it extremely difficult to find warnings:

[image]

How can I get newlines in between each call to **GCC**? Maybe get the warnings to stand out a bit more?

Comment: Something like `@echo Compiling $<; @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@;` ?

Comment: @user657267 Please sign in and make that an answer so you can get some credit. That's the cleanest and most simplest answer I've found yet, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can silence the command itself and replace it with something shorter.

```
CPPFLAGS := -MMD -MP
CFLAGS   := -pthread -Wextra -Wall -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wcast-qual -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum -Wconversion -Wunreachable-code
LDLIBS   := -lm

objects := $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard *.c))
deps    := $(objects:.o=.d)

.PHONY: all clean

prog: $(objects)
    $(LINK.o) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

%.o: %.c
    @echo Compiling $<
    @$(COMPILE.c) -o $@ $<

clean: ; $(RM) $(objects) $(deps)

-include $(deps)
```

A few other things:

- Prefer `:=` to `=`
- `LDLIBS` is the standard variable for libraries as used in make's built-in recipes
- make defaults `CC` to `cc`, which should be a link to your default compiler, you don't usually need to set `CC`
- Your `default` target will break parallel builds (`-j`), I wouldn't bother with it
- This makefile doesn't need an `all` rule, just make the target the first rule
- Watch out with `wildcard` and sources, it's usually safer to specify them manually
- You're making each object file depend on every header, just use built-in depedency generation instead (`-MMD -MP`, `include`)
- make already has recipes for object linking and compiling, reuse them
- make defaults `$(RM)` to `rm -f`

Comment: A quick addition: Rather than putting `@` in front of the `$(COMPILE.c)`, you can use `$(Q)`, where `$(Q)` resolves to `@` normally, or to blank if `$(V)` is set to 1.  This way, if you are debugging, you can type `make V=1` to see the full commands.